# How to print to console (Linux) without the standard library (libc)

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm not using the standard library, since my target x86 Linux distro is very limited.

```
#include <unistd.h>

void _start () {
      const char msg[] = "Hello world";
      write( STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof( msg ) - 1 );
}
```

I want to print text to console, but I can't, is there any other way to do this.
The code above wont work because it depends on standard library
gcc Test.cpp -o Test -nostdlib

Comment: What's not working with the code you included in your question?

Comment: It won't work because it requires libc.

Comment: It doesn't require `libc`; it requires an implementation of the system call for `write()`.  If you can't use a standard library, you'll have to create your own, containing the system calls you need, and link with that instead.  It feels like hard work, though.  Are you sure you want to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have libc, then you need to craft a `write()` system call from scratch to write to the standard output.

See this resource for the details:  http://weeb.ddns.net/0/programming/c_without_standard_library_linux.txt

Code example from the above link:

```
void* syscall5(
    void* number,
    void* arg1,
    void* arg2,
    void* arg3,
    void* arg4,
    void* arg5
);

typedef unsigned long int uintptr; /* size_t */
typedef long int intptr; /* ssize_t */

static
intptr write(int fd, void const* data, uintptr nbytes)
{
    return (intptr)
        syscall5(
            (void*)1, /* SYS_write */
            (void*)(intptr)fd,
            (void*)data,
            (void*)nbytes,
            0, /* ignored */
            0  /* ignored */
        );
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    write(1, "hello\n", 6);
    return 0;
}
```